# Is it safe for me to manage memory of a dll class if I call new and delete?

Tags: c++

If my DLL has the implementation of one of my classes, if I do new and delete on it is that okay? When is the problem regarding DLLs and who allocates what?

What if that class calls new?

```
    class InDLL {
    A* something;

    InDLL()
    {
       something = new A;
    }
    };

    ...

    //me

InDLL dll = new InDLL(); //problem?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one important rule is that **whoever allocates memory is responsible for freeing that memory, using the same allocator**.  There are no restrictions on how the memory must be allocated (it can be allocated by the main executable, by your DLL, or by some other DLL), but once it's allocated, the same module must free it.

The most important instance where you need to remember this is if your DLL has an exported function that returns a pointer to newly allocated memory.  When you do that, you must also export a corresponding function to free that memory.  For example:

```
// In mydll.dll:
class MyClass { ... };

MyClass * DLLEXPORT NewMyClass()
{
    return new MyClass;
}

void DLLEXPORT FreeMyClass(MyClass *obj)
{
    delete obj;
}
```

What you **cannot** do is allocate the memory in one module (say, by calling `NewMyClass()` above from the main executable) and free it in another module (e.g. the main executable):

```
// THIS CODE IS BUGGY, DO NOT USE:
HMODULE mydll = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");
MyClass (*NewMyClass)() = (MyClass (*)())GetProcAddress(mydll, "NewMyClass");
MyClass *obj = NewMyClass();  // allocate inside DLL
...
delete obj;  // BOOM!
```

The reason for this is that **different modules can be (and frequently are) linked against different, incompatible versions of the C/C++ runtime libraries**.  When that happens, the different modules have different ideas of how the heap works, and their implementations of `malloc`/`free` or `operator new`/`operator delete` may not agree.

For more information, see also [Allocating and freeing memory across module boundaries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is not a problem. However, you will have trouble passing objects allocated with `new` across DLL boundaries, as the caller may use a different allocator for `new` than you used.